# Creating Facebook Pages That Point to Different Subdomain URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

My Ruby on Rails app has a subdomain URL for each user's public page. Eg. username.xyz.com

I want to publish this URL on the user's Facebook Page from Rails.

So far, I have created a Facebook App and set it's Page Tab and URL.

I'm using the fbgraph gem to set this app on the facebook page. (This page will be created by the user and will have admin access of this page.)

I used this code:

```
user = FbGraph::User.me("USER_TOKEN")
account = user.accounts.select {|account| account if account.name == "PageName"}.first 
page = FbGraph::Page.new(account.identifier).fetch(:access_token =>"Access_token",:fields => :access_token)
tab = page.tab!(:app_id => "APP_ID_I_CREATED")
```

Using this code, every user's page points to the URL defined in the APP's Page Tab URL.

I want every user's page to point to their own subdomain URL (eg: user1.xyz.com)

What do I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: — I've been working on a rubygem to abstract this design pattern.  It's not finished yet but it's fully tested so if you feel like contributing, it should be easy to figure out what's going on so far.  It's about 75% done at this point but I'd like to get it out soon.  It's at http://github.com/switchrails/blotter (readme is outdated).

Answer (score 0):

The subdomain is not handled by the web server, it's handled by DNS.  So first you need to get DNS to route everyuser.xyz.com to the IP address where your web server is.

The way DNS works, you will likely have to have a DNS entry for every user.  You might be able to find an API to add DNS subdomains when you create a user.

Don't ask me about how to do this, because I don't know, and am uninterested in researching it.

You also have to get the web application to accept the request, and @lightyrs has a good description on how to do that.

Comment: I think you're head is in the right place but I think this approach is needlessly complex.  All that's needed is to have a controller action at the tab URL that redirects to the appropriate subdomain.  Facebook provides a 'signed_request' that you can decode on the server which will give you various metadata about the request and requesting user.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're trolling me at this point but I don't appreciate the downvote for an answer I am 99% sure is correct.

Comment: Your take on the question is wrong Marlin.  We're discussing facebook page tab applications.  There is no entering a URL into the browser.  This is a url that is fetched by facebook behind the scenes when a certain page tab is requested.

Comment: Is there any point where the URL is looked up in the TCP layer to direct the browser to the web server where the RoR app is running.  It still seems to me there is, and if so, the host name will go to DNS lookup but not be able to find the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

Edit: Make all of these user.mywebsite.com subdomains resolve to the same URL. At that URL:

1. Create a catch-all route that will handle all traffic originating from `*.facebook.com`.
2. Point that route to a controller action that decodes `params[:signed_request]`.
3. The decoded signed request will yield the facebook id of the page that is responsible for the request.
4. Fetch the user in your system that is an admin of the page in question.
5. Fetch the user's subdomain.
6. Redirect to the subdomain.

Currently, this is the most common way of solving this problem, however, I'd like to see a solution from facebook in the future that allows us to have some kind of dynamic tab URL based on the page, user, and referral context.

Comment: Generally, a browser connects to a web server via Uniform Resource Locator or URL, which is bound to DNS.

Comment: I'm just saying, this is a good description of how to get the RoR web app to accept the http request once it is received, but a user1.xyz.com URL won't get to the RoR web server without DNS routing it there.